# Powershell mysql connector timing out despite high connection timeout value

Tags: mysql, powershell

Pretty confused here.  Running a mysql query from Powershell using the Mysql connector.  It is timing out after 41 seconds every time.  Here is my connection string:

server=mysqlserver;port=3406;uid=admin;pwd=admin;database=MyDatabase;Connection Timeout=120

I even have the script spitting out the timeout using $Connection_cld.ConnectionTimeout, and it verifies it is 120 seconds.

However the query still always times out at 41 seconds, as per wrapping the command in Measure-Command.  Such an odd number to be timing out, but I can't get past it.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$Connection_cld = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$Connection_cld.ConnectionString = $CloudDB_string
$Connection_cld.Open()
$Connection_cld.ConnectionTimeout
$Command_cld = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query_cld, $Connection_cld)
$DataAdapter_cld = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command_cld)
$DataSet_cld = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$time = (measure-command {$RecordCount_cld = $dataAdapter_cld.Fill($DataSet_cld, "data")}).totalseconds
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: ConnectionTimeout is the timeout value for establishing a connection to MySQL, it won't change the query timeout. Looking for the right one now, but you could try CommandTimeout or QueryTimeout.

Comment: Where would I set QueryTimeout?  In the connection string as well?  I can't find any docs on that.

Comment: If that the answer in the dupe does not help explain why and we can open this again.